# Cannot use mysql on another instance using Vagrant

Tags: vagrant

I have two machines in my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define "mysql" do |mysql|
    mysql.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"
    mysql.vm.network "private_network", ip: "99.0.33.20"
    mysql.vm.provision "shell", inline: ". /vagrant/scripts/vagrant_mysql.sh"
  end

  config.vm.define "web" do |web|
    web.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"
    web.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
    web.vm.network "private_network", ip: "99.0.33.10"
    web.vm.provision "setup",
      type: "shell",
      inline: ". /vagrant/scripts/vagrant_web.sh"
  end
end
```

I want to be able to connect from `web` to `mysql`, however this doesn't work. From the `mysql` box, I can use `mysql -uroot -p` and it connects fine. However using `mysql -h99.0.33.20 -uroot -p` from the web box doesn't work. `nmap`ing port 3306 shows it closed. `ufw` is not enabled on either machine.

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
99.0.33.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1

vagrant@vagrant:~$ ifconfig eth1
eth1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr []
      inet addr:99.0.33.10  Bcast:99.0.33.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:86 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:48 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:21752 (21.7 KB)  TX bytes:3410 (3.4 KB)
```

How can I find out what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `bind-address` in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` from `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0`.